# How to support custom domains for SaaS app built on AWS and using ELB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elb, saas, sni

Web-app is running on EC2 instances and is behind ELB.
Tenants are registered with sub-domain, e.g. http://acme.myapp.io 
I'm looking for a way to implement custom domains support so that users can use their own owned domain, e.g. http://app.acme.com to access app.

The problem is that we are using HTTPS only and I see no way to use multiple SNI SSL certificates with ELB.